# php sessions auto incrementing a session value using pagination

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to create a simple multiple choice quiz site using php and want to be able to auto increment the score of the user when a radiobutton is selected and the scores automatically incremented the number of correct answers and the number of wrong answers but anytime the radio button is selected and the user submits the values are reset though i'm trying to use sessions to make it look neater i used pagination instead of displaying all results on one page. any help will be appreciated. im a newbie by the way

```
<?php
include('beginsession.php');
?>enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pagination</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    //require_once('score.php');
    $options='A';
    $results_per_page = 1;
    $questions = "SELECT * FROM questionsdb";
    $result=mysqli_query($Connection,$questions);
    $number_of_results= mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    //{
    //  echo $row['Question_Num'].''.$row['Question'].'<br>';
    //}
    //determine number of pages
    $number_of_pages=($number_of_results/$results_per_page);
    //check current page
    if (!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page =1;
    }
    else
    {
        $page =$_GET['page'];
    }
    //determine starting number
     $starting_number=($page-1)*$results_per_page;
//display results
    $questions="SELECT * FROM questionsdb LIMIT " . $starting_number . ',' .$results_per_page;

    $result=mysqli_query($Connection,$questions);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['Question_Num'].''.$row['Question'].'<br>';
    }
    $choices= mysqli_query($Connection,"SELECT * FROM answers WHERE Num=$page");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($choices))
{

echo "<table border='1'>";


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['letter'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Answer'] . "</td>";
//echo "<td><input type='radio' name=($page) value=($options)/></td>";
//echo '<td><center><input type = "checkbox"name="name1"/>&nbsp;</td>';
echo "</tr>";
//echo $Correct;
echo $options  ++;

}
?>
<?php
$correct=0;
$wrong=0;
$_SESSION['correct']=$correct;
$_SESSION['wrong']=$wrong;
$scored=$_SESSION['correct'];
$notscored=$_SESSION['wrong'];
?>
Choice:
<?php 
$choiceErr="";
$choice="";
if (empty($_POST["choice"])) {
    $choiceErr = "choice is required";
  } else {
    $choice = test_input($_POST["choice"]);
  }
  function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<form method ="post" action=<?php echo "connection.php?page=$page";?>>
<input type="radio" name="choice"
<?php if (isset($choice) && $choice=="A") echo "checked";?>
value="A">"A"
<input type="radio" name="choice"
<?php if (isset($choice) && $choice=="B") echo "checked";?>
value="B">B
<input type="radio" name="choice"
<?php if (isset($choice) && $choice=="C") echo "checked";?>
value="C">C
<input type="radio" name="choice"
<?php if (isset($choice) && $choice=="D") echo "checked";?>
value="D">D
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$Correct_answers= mysqli_query($Connection,"SELECT * FROM correct_answers WHERE Qnum=$page");
while ($picked=mysqli_fetch_array($Correct_answers))
{
$yes=$picked['Answer'];
echo $picked['Answer'];
}
echo "<br>";
echo $choice;
echo $yes;

if ($choice == $yes)
{
    echo "it is okay";
    $correct++;
    echo "<br>";
echo "you have gotten $scored questions correct and $notscored questions wrong";
}
else
{
    echo "it is not okay";
    $wrong++;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "you have gotten $correct questions correct and $wrong questions wrong";
}
echo "<br>";




?>
<?php



/*$Correct_answers= mysqli_query($Connection,"SELECT * FROM correct_answers WHERE Qnum=$page");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($Correct_answers))
{
echo $row['Answer'];
if ($row['Answer']=='$choice')
{
    echo "it is correct";
}
else
{
    echo "it is wrong";
}
}*/

    //display link to pages
    for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
    {

        echo '<a href="connection.php?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>';
    }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: why don't you use data tables for pagination, it has server side pagination as well

Comment: Are you starting the session with [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)? Also, I'm not sure if all of that code is in one document, but it seems like you're setting `$correct` and `$wrong` to zero before storing the values in the session.

Comment: solved it seemed like i was resetting the session values to zero everytime the next page loaded

Comment: anyway all the code is in one document but the session and database connection are in other files